# How is "Connect to the instance" accomplished, for connecting to an EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Connecting to an EC2 instance requires a user account. On *[Manage users on your Linux instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html)*,

> **Create a user account**
>
> First create the user account, and then add the SSH public key that
> allows the user to connect to and log into the instance.
>
> To create a user account
>
> 1. Create a new key pair. You must provide the .pem file to the user for whom you are creating the user account. They must use this file to
>    connect to the instance.
> 2. Retrieve the public key from the key pair that you created in the previous step.
>
>    ```
>    $  ssh-keygen -y -f /path_to_key_pair/key-pair-name.pem
>    ```

> The command returns the public key.
>
> 3. Connect to the instance.
> 4. Use the adduser command to create the user account and add it to the system (with an entry in the /etc/passwd file). ...

How is "3. Connect to the instance" accomplished?

Does that require a user account? What if I haven't created one yet?

---

Security group's rule:

[image]

Comment: All EC2 images provided by Amazon have a default user you can connect to.  Check out [the directions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstances.html) for options on connecting.

Comment: Better to use Session Manager to connect.

Answer (score 1):

When launching an Amazon EC2 instance, you can select a Keypair that has previously been created or loaded into AWS.

When the instance boots, code on the AMI retrieves the keypair and inserts it into the default user's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

You can then SSH into the instance using the keypair.

Or, there are alternative ways to connect, such as using [AWS Systems Manager Session Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html).

Comment: Thanks. How can I figure out whether "when launching an Amazon EC2 instance, I have selected a Keypair that has previously been created or loaded into AWS"? If I haven't can I select a keypair to a running or stopped instance?

Comment: No, this process only happens on first boot of the instance. If you haven't done anything with the instance, then you can Terminate it and launch a new one. Alternatively, if the instance has the Systems Manager agent installed and you have sufficient IAM permissions, you can use AWS Systems Manager Session Manager to connect instead.

Comment: Thanks. My AWS CLI command for connection is like `ssh -i "MyKeyPair.pem" admin@ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com`, but it always says "ssh: connect to host ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection timed out". What may be wrong?

Comment: What is the configuration of your Security Group? It should be permitting in Inbound connection on port 22 to your IP address.

Comment: I have uploaded a screenshot to my post. Do I share too much information for security concern? I am using the "default" group. Is it by default permitting everything, correct?

Comment: No. It is only permitting inbound connections that come from resources associated with the `sg-0f75607a90f6ecaf8` security group. Instead, it should permit inbound access on port 22 with the source being IP address.

Comment: I saw this in aws cli user guide. Is `aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-0f75607a90f6ecaf8 --protocol tcp --port 22 --cidr [my-ip]` the command to set up the permission? Can I run it when the EC2 instance is running? The command outputs `An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress operation: CIDR block [my-ip] is malformed`

Comment: I recommend that you configure it in the Amazon EC2 management console. It is more friendly. FYI, that command is referencing a specific Security Group (`sg-0f75607a90f6ecaf8`), which is irrelevant for your needs.